# Can't pack a widget inside a sibling toplevel

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to `pack` (or `place`) a widget which is child of the root toplevel `.` inside another toplevel, that is a child of `.` itself. That is,

```
% toplevel .tl
.tl
% frame .f
.f
% pack .f -in .tl
can't pack .f inside .tl
```

However, I've found this code *almost* works:

```
% frame .tl
.tl
% frame .f
.f
% pack .f -in .tl
% wm manage .tl
```

I said *almost*, because `.f` is not visible. It's a bit strange, because if I put a button inside `.f`, such as

```
button .f.b -text FooBar
pack .f.b
```

I see the empty space reserved by the geometry manager, but no widget is visible.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what and why, and the `pack`, `grid` and `place` man pages don't help.

---

**Edit: some details about what I'm doing**

I'm trying to build a snit widget which automates some toplevel creation stuff. One thing I usually do is putting a `ttk::frame` inside every toplevel I create, and managing it using a `pack ... -fill both -expand true` command.

My snidget should always do it, but I'd like to hide it from the user perspective, so that any change to the implementation wouldn't break existing code.

The simple way is this

```
snit::widget Toplevel {
    hulltype toplevel
    component f

    constructor {args} {
        set f [ttk::frame $self.f -padding 2]
        pack $f -fill both -expand 1

        $self configurelist $args
    }
}
```

but the user must know about the `f` component, and create other widgets as children of it.

So, I tried another solution: I use a `ttk::frame` widget as hull type, then build a *sibling* toplevel of the hull, and try to put the hull inside the toplevel.

The code I tried is similar to the following:

```
snit::widget Toplevel {
    hulltype ttk::frame
    component tl

    constructor {args} {
        set segments [split $self .]
        set wname [join [lreplace $segments end end _[lindex $segments end]] .]

        set tl [frame $wname -width 100 -height 100]
        pack $self -in $tl -fill both -expand 1
        wm manage $tl

        $self configurelist $args
    }
}
```

If it would work as expected, the user could write something like this:

```
% Toplevel .t
.t
% button .t.b -text Foobar
.t.b
% pack .t.b
```

and would get a button inside the toplevel `.t` build using the snidget.

Comment: Try using `% toplevel .tl % pack [frame .tl.f]`.

Comment: In my case, the frame *is not* a child of the toplevel, but a *sibling*. What you suggest is the usual case and, of course, works like a charm

Comment: Have you tried adding `raise .f` just after `pack .f -in .tl` in your case that almost works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widgets *except for toplevels* are arranged in a strict hierarchy of containment; the widget `.foo` contains the widget `.foo.bar`, which in turn contains `.foo.bar.grill`, etc. Toplevel widgets are actually all children of the root window.

There are exactly two things you can do to change this.

1. You can use `wm manage` (requires 8.5 or later) to turn a standard frame widget into a toplevel, and `wm forget` to reverse this (you'll have to also then re-`pack`/re-`grid` it too). (I don't think this is supported on OSX/Aqua.)

   ```
   frame .foo
   # Define its contents...
   wm manage .foo
   ```

   ```
   # Later...
   wm forget .foo
   pack .foo
   ```

   This is a useful pair of operations for making torn-off windows like toolbars. There's even a demo in the Tk widget demo.
2. You can turn a frame (or toplevel) into a container widget at creation time (set the `-container` option to true in the creation options; it can't be done later). You can then get the ID of the window widget (with `winfo id`) and tell a toplevel *at creation time* to use that widget ID as its parent via the `-use` option.

   ```
   frame .foo -container 1
   set id [winfo id .foo]
   toplevel .bar -use $id
   ```

   Note that in this case, on Unix/X11 those IDs can be passed to other processes and used, and need not actually refer to windows created by Tk. (Some applications can also do the reverse, embedding themselves inside a window given by ID that was defined by Tk.) On Windows and OSX/Aqua, the IDs are only guaranteed to work within a single process.

What I don't know is whether the operation you want to perform can be done by either of these two possible operations; you're not quite clear about the higher-level perspective of what you're trying to do. They don't mix particularly well, as `-container` and `-use` are creation-time-only options, and are subsequently read-only, and you can't change the name hierarchy (that's totally fixed after creation). Really sophisticated stuff may require you to step back and formally define a model that you have multiple widget layouts being views of.

Comment: I added a longer explaination of what I'm trying to get.

Comment: I suspect that you may be able to achieve your goal by making the frame a child of the toplevel, and renaming the widget commands. Not sure how that would interact with snit, though.

Comment: how to do from frame to frame shifting of UI?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't possible, Marco. All widgets must be children of their top-level containers.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I know I can reparent a toplevel inside a frame using the `-use` and `-container` options and the `winfo id` command; moreover, using the `-in` option of the `pack`/`place` geometry managers I can put a widget inside a sibling, and no parent-child relation is involved.

E.g.
`% frame .f1`
`% frame .f2 ;# this is a sibling of .f1`
`% pack .f1`
`% pack .f2 -in .f1`
works.

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure. Any widget that isn't itself a toplevel widget is only instantiated within the context of its top-level parent. You can only `pack .f2 -in .f1` when they both have the same toplevel window.